Change of variables mapping (xy)/(x+y) to a sum or product
I've been working on a double integral of the form
$$
\int_\alpha^\infty dx\ f(x)\int_\beta^\infty dy\ g(y)\ e^{-a\frac{xy}{x+y}}\left(\frac{xy}{x+y}\right)^b,
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are not particularly relevant to the question.
I've tried several approaches to solve it, but each one leads some way or another to a sum over generalized hypergeometric functions, which for my purposes is nearly useless. I now think the solution (if one exists in closed form) could conceivably be found if I can factor the integral through some sort of change of variables or integral transform, one which either maps
$$
\frac{xy}{x+y}\mapsto u+v
$$
or
$$
\frac{xy}{x+y}\mapsto u\times v
$$
for some new variables $u$ and $v$. Is this possible? I'm looking for a way to completely factor the $x$- and $y$-integrals, so clearly something like
$$
x\mapsto x\sqrt{x+y},\qquad y\mapsto y\sqrt{x+y}
$$
is not satisfactory.
Thank you for the help!

I'm not sure that $f$ and $g$ really are irrelevant, because after you perform the substitution you're going to have to deal with $f(x(u, v))$ and $g(y(u, v))$ and there's no guarantee that those function will separate out nicely.

Well, unless the change of variables is particularly messy, I'm not worried. They are typically rational functions, so if the CoV is rational, they will be as well. What I'm really looking for is an integral representation for the explicit part of the integrand that turns the exponential into a product of exponentials and the parenthetical expression into a sum. Anyway, the main reason I don't care about $f$ and $g$ for now is that they are different for different problems. The only part that persists is that which I explicitly wrote, so I want to find a general strategy to treat that part.
